# How to give space or next line feature in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my java script code:

```
function for_approve(){
var approve = confirm(format_stock_id.length + 
               "&nbsp;Stock Record(s) is selected for approval.<br /> 
               Do You Want to send it for Approval");

}
```

It gives me result as:

```
3 &nbsp;Stock Record(s) is selected for approval.<br />Do You Want to send it for Approval
```

What should i do for space and new line.

Comment: `window.confirm` does not take any HTML. Just use plain text or even better, don't use `window.confirm`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to make the sentence a little neater with regard to plurals, you could do this:

```
if (format_stock_id.length == 1) {
    var approve = confirm("1 Stock Record is selected for approval.\n 
    Do You Want to send it for Approval");
} else {
    var approve = confirm(format_stock_id.length + " Stock Records are selected for approval.\n
    Do You Want to send them for Approval");
}
```

Little things like that make a good amount of difference in the final product.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `\n` symbol:

```
function for_approve(){
  var approve = confirm(format_stock_id.length + 
               " Stock Record(s) is selected for approval.\n 
               Do You Want to send it for Approval");

}
```

You can check this right here. Open console in your browser and write: `alert("bob\nbob");`

**EXAMPLE**

Command:

[image: command]

Result:

[image: example]

P.S.: Same for space. You don't have to use escape-query `&nbsp;`. Just use   (simple space).

Answer (score 0):

To jump to next line you need to use \n and for space no need to to write &nbsp, simply write whitespace character,

```
function for_approve(){
var approve = confirm(format_stock_id.length + " Stock Record(s) is selected for approval.\n Do You Want to send it for Approval");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JS Escape Characters in a string (ref: http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp) :

```
\'  single quote
\"  double quote
\\  backslash
\n  new line
\r  carriage return
\t  tab
\b  backspace
\f  form feed
```

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
\xa0
```

space

```
\n
```

new line

your code will be:

```
function for_approve(){
   var approve = confirm(format_stock_id.length + "\xa0 Stock Record(s) is selected for approval.\n Do You Want to send it for Approval");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use "br" ex: console.log("hello world 
");