# What is wrong with this alert message formatting?

Tags: javascript

I am pretty sure this is just a formatting mistake, but i am having trouble seeing what I have done wrong.  I am trying to make 3 lines in the alert. I know my mistake has to do with my placement of \n because when i remove it the alert functions fine, it just wraps the text in the message box.

```
alert("Your Order Total = $" + T.toFixed(2) + 
\n "Your toltal Quanity is " + cq + 
\n "Thank You for your order have a wonderfull day" );
```

Comment: /n needs put in quotes

Comment: Why is a question where the solution is to put text that is part of a string literal in quotes getting upvoted?

Answer (score 3):

The newlines goes inside the string

```
alert("Your Order Total = $" + T.toFixed(2) + 
"\nYour total Quantity is " + cq + 
"\nThank You for your order have a wonderful day" );
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/XKGbe/)

Answer (score 0):

### Use this:

```
alert("Your Order Total = $" + T.toFixed(2) + 
"\nYour toltal Quanity is " + cq + 
"\nThank You for your order have a wonderful day" );
```

### Explanation

Your code doesn't work, because you use `\n` symbol not inside the quotes. You have to use it inside the quotes.

### [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23195633/how-to-give-space-or-next-line-feature-in-javascript/23195666#23195666)

Comment: Not in brackets, you rather mean "quotes". And even that is rather irrelevant, the proper term would be "inside the/a string literal"